# _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex) doesn't show up properly after checking and granting storage permission in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I added a condition block where RequestPermissionPage widget would show when permission status is returned as denied. It shows the RequestPermissionPage widget and the button to request permission also works as intended but after giving the permission, the main page still wont show properly.

I'm using permission_handler with provider.
Here is my code:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final AppPermissionState _perm = AppPermissionState();
  final List<Widget> _pages = [const HomePage(), RecentPage(), StoragePage()];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _perm.checkPermissionStatus();
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _perm.permissionStatus.isGranted
          ? _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex) //this doesn't show after requesting
          : const RequestPermissionPage(), //this works as intended
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.folder_open), label: "Library"),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse_rounded), label: "Recent"),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.storage_outlined), label: "Storage"),
        ],
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
        onDestinationSelected: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class RequestPermissionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RequestPermissionPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppPermissionState>(
      builder: (context, permissionStateValue, child) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text("This feature require storage permission"),
              ),
              FilledButton.tonal(
                onPressed: () {
                  permissionStateValue.requestPermission(); //this works as intended too
                },
                child: const Text("Grant Permission"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Permission provider:

```
class AppPermissionState extends ChangeNotifier {
  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;

  PermissionStatus get permissionStatus => _permissionStatus;

  Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> checkPermissionStatus() async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
  }
}
```

Tested on Android Q, S and T

Permissions already mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Tried changing checkPermissionStatus() in AppPermissionState to the following code

```
Future<void> checkPermissionStatus() async {
    await requestPermission();
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Expected to show only the content in _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex) right after granting permission and without restarting the app.

But shows RequestPermissionPage even after granting permission, strangely after restarting the app I can toggle elements in _pages and RequestPermissionPage doesn't show after changing bottom navbar pages but RequestPermissionPage shows up every time app is opened. How do I fix it?

Comment: The problem is resolved, check my answer for the updated working code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem is resolved. Instead of calling `AppPermissionState` outside `build()`, I had to call it inside `build()`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _perm = Provider.of<AppPermissionState>(context);
    _perm.checkPermissionStatus();
    if (_perm.permissionStatus.isGranted) {
      return _buildHomePage(); //returns successfully when condition is true
    } else {
      return const RequestPermissionPage(); //returns successfully when condition is false
    }
  }
```

and in `RequestPermissionPage`, turns out there isn't need for Consumer builder. Instead replaced Cosumer builder with this in a `StatelessWidget` class:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final permissionStateValue = Provider.of<AppPermissionState>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text("This feature require storage permission"),
            ),
            FilledButton.tonal(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  ),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                  )),
              onPressed: () {
                permissionStateValue.requestPermission();
              },
              child: const Text("Request Permission"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The permission provider stays the same

```dart
class AppPermissionState extends ChangeNotifier {
  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;

  PermissionStatus get permissionStatus => _permissionStatus;

  Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> checkPermissionStatus() async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
  }
}
```